# java- engine.eval("String with equation"); and i want to get an output of BigDecimal

Tags: java

I tried several ways to get a BigDecimal as an output from engine.eval() with no result. an example of a code that i tried is bellow:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino");
String calculation= "8+8+3*56";
BigDecimal finalResult= BigDecimal.ZERO; 


try {
                finalResult = (BigDecimal) engine.eval(calculation);
} 
catch (ScriptException e) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong input.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `String calculation = "new java.math.BigDecimal(8).add(new java.math.BigDecimal(8)).add(new java.math.BigDecimal(3)).multiply(new java.math.BigDecimal(56))";`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to be running **Java 6 or 7**, because only those versions of Java include the `"rhino"` JavaScript engine. In Java 8 to 14, the JavaScript engine is named `"nashorn"`. Java 15+ no longer ships with a JavaScript engine. To run with Java 6 to 14, specify name `"JavaScript"`.

Second, the expression returns a number, but the exact type is not necessarily well-defined. I believe it will always be `Double` for JavaScript, but if you use another expression engine, the type may differ, so it's best to coerce the result to `BigDecimal` yourself.

That is however easily done as follows:

```java
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String calculation = "8+8+3*56";
Object result = engine.eval(calculation);
BigDecimal finalResult = (result instanceof BigDecimal
                          ? (BigDecimal) result
                          : BigDecimal.valueOf(((Number) result).doubleValue()));
System.out.println(finalResult);
```

*Output*

```
184.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
finalResult = new BigDecimal(engine.eval(calculation));
```

Assuming the output of the evaluation will also be a String. If the output of the engine evaluation is a double or integer, simply add a Integer/Double.toString(evaluation) within the BigDecimal initialization.

Comment: That won't compile.